Spring Cloud Open Feign Client send only first key-value using POST form-url-encoded
Have some request
@FeignClient(
        name = "FeignServer",
        url = "url",
        configuration = FeignProxyConfiguration.class)
public interface ServerFeign {

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<String> sendCode(@RequestBody Dto dto);

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
public class Dto {
    @FormProperty("val_n1")
    private String valN1;

    @FormProperty("val_n2")
    private String valN2;

    @FormProperty("val_n3")
    private String valN3;
    
}

 @Bean
    @Primary
    @Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public FormEncoder feignFormEncoder() {
        return new FormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(this.messageConverters));
    }

Tunneling proxy server works good. But reciver got only first value 'val_n1', how can I send all values using POST form-url-encoded ?

There seems to be no problem, it should be a problem with FormEncoder, you can try to cancel FormEncoder to see the exact log message...

The problem was in url paramets, like host/?param1=1&param2=2&parm3=3, only first param recieved, I have changed param to body. Change Feign client to RestTemplate.
Some code, RestTemplate with proxy.
